# ColorDrawable doesn't draw on its bounds

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set `ColorDrawable` with bounds for backgroundDrawable to `View` and it's just not working properly, using following code:

```
ColorDrawable d = new ColorDrawable(getContext().getResources()
        .getColor(R.color.red));
d.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 20);

convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Result is that the convertView background gets filled with red color here.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so when using `Drawable` as background of `View` bounds change when the `View` does it's layout. So having strict bounds, I need to extend `Drawable` and have private `Rect` for it's bounds to use.